# How to include HTML contents from another site? I have access to both sites

Tags: asp.net

I have a site which is using DNN (DotNetNuke) as a content management system. I am using another site for my event registrations. I have sent them my template; which displays the basics including a hover menu with many different items in it.

Issue is - as I update the menu on my site using DNN, I need it to be reflected on the site using my template - without me having to send them a new file. Anyone have suggetsions on how to approach this?

I don't want to send the events provider all of the DNN DLLs as well as my database login information in order to render the menu.

I created a page on my site that is something like 'menu.aspx' - this produces the menu in HTML format, however it has tags like  in it that I'd like to remove before serving it to them.

What is the best approach for this? Do I need to write a custom server control using XMLHttp? Can I accomplish this in Javascript?

Any advice much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Double post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298411/how-to-include-html-contents-from-another-site-i-have-access-to-both-sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: As Vincent E. pointed out, this will only work if they're on the same domain - my bad.

If you are unwilling or unable to use frames, then I would set up an ashx on your DNN server which renders the menu (if you've got it in a user control all the better, as you can just instatiate it and `Render` it directly to the output stream) and then just make an Ajax call to that from your events page and insert it directly into the DOM.

Here's a quick and hacky jquery-based example of the events page end of things:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function RenderMenu(data)
{
    $('#Menu').html(data);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : 'http://localhost/AjaxHandlers/Menu.ashx',
            data : '',
            success : RenderMenu,
        });
    });

</script>
```

You'll want an empty div with the ID 'Menu' on the page where you want your menu to sit, but apart from that you're good to go.

If for whatever reason you can't get the menu HTML in an isolated way, then you'll need to do some text processing in `RenderMenu`, but it's still do-able.

Comment: This won't work if the two websites are not on the same domain, because of the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 2):

If both sites are hosted on the same domain (eg site1.domain.com and site2.domain.com) you can use JavaScript and XmlHttpRequest to insert code from one site to another. Otherwise, the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents you from using AJAX.

If they're not on the same domain but you have access to the page on their website, you can simply include there a JS script from your site :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite.com/code.js"></script>
```

In the JS, simply `document.write()` what you want on the page. This way, you can easily change the content of the page on their site without having to send them a new file.

Finally, you can also use an iframe on their site, pointing to a page on yours.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a web expert, so don't shoot me.

Can't you just put their registration form into an iFrame in DNN ?